# Points of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the distance between two points is an odd integer.

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic, normed-spaces

I recently heard about the following result : "If there exists $x_1,\ldots,x_{n+2}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for all $i\neq j$, $\|x_i-x_j\|$ is an odd integer (where $\|\cdot\|$ is the euclidean norm of $\mathbb{R}^n$), then 
$16$ divides $n+2$." I have absolutely no clue why it is true, some help would be appreciated to prove this result.

Comment: This sounds like a wild result. Can you give us a reference? It's expected that question askers do some research / thinking of their own before posting.

Comment: My teacher told me about this result, it is an exercise from an exam, this is all I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a contest question rather than an examination question. Had this been an examination question, it would be a very poor one, because its solution seems to rely on multiple tricks that are alien to most students.

Let $x_{n+2}=0$. Then $\|x_i\|\,(=\|x_i-x_{n+2}\|)$ and $\|x_i-x_j\|$ are odd integers when $i,j\le n+1$ and $i\ne j$. Since the square of any integer is congruent to $1$ modulo $8$ (because $(2k+1)^2=4k(k+1)+1$ and $k(k+1)$ is even), both $\|x_i\|^2$ and $2\langle x_i,x_j\rangle=\|x_i\|^2+\|x_j\|^2-\|x_i-x_j\|^2$ are congruent to $1$ modulo $8$. In turn,
\begin{aligned}
2\|x_i\|^2&\equiv2&\mod16,\\
2\langle x_i,x_j\rangle&\equiv1\ \text{ or }\ 9&\mod16.
\end{aligned}
Let $G=2X^TX$ where $X=\pmatrix{x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_{n+1}}$. The above congruences show that, modulo $16$, all diagonal entries of $G$ are congruent to $2$ and each off-diagonal entry is congruent to $1$ or $9$, but it can happen that some off-diagonal entries are congruent to $1$ and some are congruent to $9$.

Since $G$ is symmetric, if we replace some symmetric pair of off-diagonal entries by an indeterminate $t$, then $\det(G)$ is a polynomial of the form $p(t)=at^2+2bt+c$ for some integers $a,b$ and $c$. Since $p(1)$ is congruent to $p(9)$ modulo $16$, we may change all off-diagonal entries of $G$ to $1$ without changing the value of $\det(G)$ modulo $16$. (This clever argument is due to @S.Dolan.)

In other words, $\det(G)$ is congruent to $\det(I_{n+1}+ee^T)=n+2$ modulo $16$. Yet, we also have $\det(G)=\det(2X^TX)=0$ because $X$ has more columns than rows. Therefore $16|(n+2)$.

---

**Update.** I should have exercised due diligence first. A quick internet search reveals that this problem was posed and solved in Graham *et al.*, [*Are there $n+2$ points in $E^n$ with odd integral distances?*](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1974.11993491) AMM 81(1):21-25, 1974. I haven't access to this journal, but in the preview of this article, it was written that

> Theorem 1. For the existence of $n+2$ points in $E^n$ so that the distance between any two of them is an odd integer, it is necessary and sufficient that $n+2\equiv0\ (\operatorname{mod} 16)$.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Why if $G=2X^TX$ then $\det(G)=\det(X^TX)$? It shouldn't be $\det(2X^TX)$? 2) $p\vee q\to p$ is not true in general (it is true $p\wedge q\to p$). Apply this to the last sentence where $p\vee q=16\mid(n+2)\vee16\mid9^{n+1}(n+2)$.

Comment: @manooooh (1) It's just a typo. (2) $\gcd(16,9)=1$. Therefore in both cases $16$ must divide $n+2$.

Comment: I wonder if the real answer is you can never have it, even if $16|(n+2)$

Comment: @RossMillikan Interestingly, if there are only $n+1$ points in $\mathbb R^n$, as long as the prespecified distances satisfy strict triangle inequalities, it seems that (if I am not mistaken) the distances (whether they are odd integers or real numbers) are always realizable.

Comment: @user1551: yes, you can just make an $n-$ simplex.  The problem comes with the last one.

Comment: In the matrix G it seems to be assumed that the $2\langle x_i,x_j\rangle$ are all 1 or all 9 mod 16. Why can't some be 1 and some 9?

Comment: @S.Dolan Ugh, you're right. I'll see if this can be fixed. If you have any idea, please feel free to post your own answer or edit mine.

Comment: I have seen this use of a matrix before but it was a long time ago and I was basically relearning about it from your post. I will think about this though but I'm sure I'll see your fix first!

Comment: On second thoughts I think it's easy. The effect of changing one symmetric pair of $1$s to $9$s or vice versa changes the determinant by 0 mod 16.

Comment: Yes. If the symmetric pair have value $x$ then the determinant will have  the form $ax^2+2bx+c$ with $a,b,c$ integers and so it does not matter if $x$ is $1$ or $9$.

Comment: @S.Dolan Great idea! I'll incorporate it into my answer.